# Why was the name 'Enterprise' chosen (out of universe)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In *TOS*, *TNG*, *TAS* and, of course, *ENT*, we witness the voyages of the many different USS Enterprises.  Going back to *TOS*, though, my question is: **why did the producers settle on the name *Enterprise* as the name of the ship?**

I understand it was originally called the *USS Yorktown* NCC-1700 but then they changed it to *Enterprise*.  **What influenced this change?**

Comment: I tried searching for a similar question but couldn't find one - one of those 'why hasn't this already been asked?' moments!

Comment: It's a surprisingly common name for ships used for exploration in real-world history, but I've no idea if that influenced the producers.

Comment: Wild guess suggests its after the Enterprise CVN-65 aircraft carrier (Enterprise class) which was as well the first nuclear powered carrier. So the space ship Enterprise would represent exactly the same thing as the brand new, cutting edge ass-kicking, makes-your-country-proud sea vessel. Star trek was written in 1964, two years after USS Enterprise entered into service

Comment: Just speculating here, but the USS Enterprise (CV-6) a.k.a. the "Big E" was a legendary WW2 aircraft carrier that participated in more major actions against the Japanese than any other ship. It was a _Yorktown_ class aircraft carrier commissioned before WW2 and was one of only 3 such pre-WW2 carriers to survive the war (and the most decorated warship from WW2). I suspect this was a significant influence on the naming of the flagship.

Comment: [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise#Vessels). There have been 15 British ships, 8 (soon to be 9) US ships, and a space shuttle all with that name. Why wouldn't the flagship be named Enterprise?

Comment: @Kevin : But the shuttle wasn't built until 1976...

Comment: @Kevin You've got the causal relationship backwards with the Shuttle Orbiter. The Orbiter was named after the TOS ship because of a fan write-in campaign to NASA, not the other way around.

Comment: *Enterprise* is perhaps *the* most fabled ship's name in the US Navy - counting back to the days of the Continental Navy there have been eight ships named USS Enterprise since 1775 (not including the newest one, a Gerald R. Ford-class aircraft carrier which won't be commissioned until ~2025). My ship used to tie up across the pier from Building 65 back in the early 80's - CVN-65 was sometimes called Building 65 because (as the story goes) someone was wandering up and down the pier looking for her, and when she was pointed out to him he said, "That's a SHIP?! I thought it was a BUILDING!" :-)

Comment: and let's not forget the ship is actually named *USS* Enterprise, like the carriers, which is already quite a stretch. It should really be called UFPS Enterprise, for "United Federation of Planets Ship")

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked, but the Navy has a [long history of ships named U.S.S. Enterprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ships_of_the_United_States_Navy_named_Enterprise). Since Star Trek is basically "future Navy in space" why not keep the tradition going?

Comment: Only a small point but I heard they chose 1701 because they wanted it to be visually easy to recognise (no 3 8 or 6 9 for example). So I guess 1700 got a +1 of its own for that reason.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the present time, I cannot find a statement by Roddenberry concerning the change from *Yorktown* to *Enterprise*, nor from *TOS* personnel such as Matt Jefferies.

In lieu of a statement, I will offer speculations.

## Historical and technological significance

When Roddenberry pitched the show in 1964, the actual USS Yorktown (CV-5) would have been remembered for being sunk by the Japanese during the Battle of Midway, only 22 years earlier.

**The USS Enterprise (CV-6) survived not only the battle but the war as the *most decorated US ship*.**

Not only has the Enterprise name been given to a healthy line of decorated ships, it also would have represented the cutting edge: **the CVN-65 Enterprise, built in the early 1960s, was the world's first nuclear-powered aircraft carrier**.  This powerful symbol of progress and achievement may have had an impact on the naming of everyone's favourite starship a few years later.

## Universality

At a practical level, "Enterprise" sounds more universal and less US-centric than "Yorktown", and hence fits with Roddenberry's pan-humanist beliefs.

## Sexiness

It sounds **sexier**.  Note that in Roddenberry's [series pitch](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/1_Original_Series/Star_Trek_Pitch.pdf), Robert April was the captain.  **Enterprise + Kirk** is decidedly sexier than **Yorktown + April**.

Comment: Note also that Spock was red-skinned and "half-Martian" in the original pitch.

Comment: “In lieu of a statement, I will offer speculations.” That’s the spirit!

Comment: Although this of course isn't as good as anything official, these are **very** sound speculations; great work as always!

Comment: @N_Soong The question made HNQ, so if anything official is out there someone will find it. Until then, this is pretty good.

Comment: +1. While *Enterprise* is indeed more universal than *Yorktown*, it's still associated with free-market capitalism. So it suggests that in this future, the USA has triumphed over the USSR and Communism. Of course that is what eventually happened, but in 1964 it was by no means believed to be a foregone conclusion.

Comment: @Mast I'm not criticising the article at all, just making the observation that the ultimate answer would be a quote from Gene.  Nevertheless, this is **outstanding** speculation and very reasonable.

Comment: Damnit, the Enterprise is Sexy! It's also got to be said that 'enterprise' is a virtue/concept which the Enterprise is meant to embody, this is likely a reason for that name in the actual ship and the star ship.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit It's more likely the name is referring to the more general definition of enterprise: _a project or undertaking, typically one that is difficult or requires effort._

Comment: The Enterprise isn't the ship, it's the series itself.

Answer (score -2):

The  USS Enterprise of Star Trek is named after the line of naval vessels in real life named Enterprise.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  I appreciate the answer, but simply citing a Wikipedia article, which, by the way, does not even provide evidence that the Enterprise *was* named after the real *Enterprise* ships, isn't valid

Comment: @Kik it's one thing to admit that you are speculating and provide little evidence, but it's another to claim that a source provides evidence for a claim when it clearly doesn't

Comment: @Kik : The question was *why did the name change from Yorktown to Enterprise*?  That's the question that I attempted to answer, and I stated clearly that I was speculating because I could not find an official statement.  This answer, however, is just a Wikipedia link and makes no attempt to answer the actual question, that is, why was the name *changed*?  I didn't downvote this answer; I'm just trying to explain why others might think mine is superior.  I do not believe that this answer meets the standards of this site.